# Flutter iOS Terminates State get data from firebase push notification

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-ios

How we can get the data of push notification to save it in our local database using flutter iOS while in terminated state?

We are using firebase admin-sdk to send push notification using the send to device function

we are using this payload

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: title,
    body: notification.message,
    sound: "default",
  },
  data: {
    click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    title: title,
    message: notification.message,
  }
};
```

with message options

```
{
    contentAvailable: true,
    priority: 'high'
  }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.